# Wordpress Payment Plugin Site-Wide Cookie Preventing Varnish Edge Caching Through Pantheon

Tags: wordpress, session-cookies, varnish, pantheon

Running in circles trying to leverage Pantheon's CDN/Varnish edge caching.

Have a Wordpress site uses the WP Simple Pay Lite plugin to process Stripe transactions on one page.  That plugin creates a session cookie to allow correct handling of payment success/failure.

That session cookie prevents caching via Varnish.  As I understand it, a lot of people run into this with WooCommerce as well, but I'm having a hard time finding a clear solution and Pantheon support is giving me the "this is beyond our support", which is fair, but it seems this would be a very common issue.

[Simple Pay's docs](https://docs.wpsimplepay.com/articles/caching-session-issues/) specifically mention Pantheon as an exception and refer to using Pantheon's Native Session plugin (which we are), which as I understand it, offloads sessions to the database.  The next step isn't really clear to me though as that alone doesn't eliminate the session, only switches how it's handled.

**So does anyone have a solid workaround for this site-wide cookie whether through Simple Pay Lite, WooCommerce or otherwise?**

If I can't get a better solution working, I suppose I could just move the payment piece to a subdomain, but would love a cleaner solution.

I've done a little looking at [selectively loading the plugin only for the one page that uses they payment form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114345/load-plugin-selectively-for-pages-or-posts-etc), but a lot of the solutions there are pretty generic and I'm not sure my level of expertise is going to get me over the hump.

Bear with me... kind of flailing here.

Comment: Having 0 knowledge of Pantheon and some of Varnish: doesn't Pantheon allow you to ignore certain cookies anywhere aside from certain pages? Because bare bones Varnish VCL allows you to do just that :)

Comment: @DanielV. - I'm getting forced into learning both and as I understand it, there is no user access to Varnish VCL with Pantheon's setup.  There was a similar question re: WooCommerce and Pantheon's Varnish setup that pointed to that (ignore specific cookies option) as an easy solution when working with Varnish, but alas... it's a no-go with Pantheon apparently.